Unable to add User to google admins directory Groups using flutter
I am authentication users using google OAuth and then trying to add that user to google directory groups. but it is giving me 403 error and i am unable to find the reason or how to resolve the issue.
Here is my function
Future<void> addUserToGroup(String userEmail) async {
    // Authenticate with Google using OAuth 2.0
    final clientId = 'My Client ID';
    final clientSecret = 'My Client Secret ID';
    print('In add user to group function');
    final clientIdFile = ClientId(clientId, clientSecret);
    final scopes = [DirectoryApi.adminDirectoryGroupMemberScope];
    print('got client idFile and Scopes and trying to get current client');
    final client = await clientViaUserConsent(clientIdFile, scopes, prompt);
    print('Got client and creating directory API');
    // Create a Directory API client
    final directoryApi = DirectoryApi(client);

    // Add user to the 'user_teacher' group
    final groupKey = teachergroup; // Replace with your group email
    final groupMember = Member()..email = userEmail;
    print('created directory api now trying to insert user in group');
    try {
      await directoryApi.members.insert(groupMember, groupKey);
      print('User added to group successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to add user to group: $e');
    }
  }

It is been 3 days since i am trying to resolve on my own but failed
i could not find relevant answer for flutter. although there is a lot of data there but not very specific to my problem. May its too easy that no one ever stuck here

The user you log in as does not have permission. Which permissions does the user have in Google Workspace?

user is a super admin in google workspace and it should not have this permission error or 403 server side error

Is the value of teacherGroup correct? I do not know if the Dart SDK requires an email address or ID. Edit your post and include a link to the SDK documentation that you are referencing. The 403 means you do not have permission. The key is to figure out what you do not have permission on.
